# How to enable quick menu in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, community, salesforce1-app, sandbox

[image]

How to enable quick menu in Salesforce ??
Please suggest.

Comment: http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-enable-quick-access-menu-in.html

Comment: First of all try to search in google before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Your Name | Setup | My Personal Information | Personal Information.

On the user detail page, click Edit, select Force.com Quick Access Menu, then click Save.